# How to trim leading character before importing to postgres?

Tags: python, excel, postgresql, csv

I have a python script that first converts an xls file to csv and then I have another script that imports this csv file into a postgres table - the UPCs in my file have leading characters that I do no want to import though. How do I trim the leading character out before importing?

```
        arg = {
            'date': date,
            'store_id': row[0].strip(),
            'store_name': row[1].strip(),
            'model_num': checkEmpty(row[12].strip()),
            'upc': row[13].strip(),
            'on_hand': row[14].strip(),
            'on_order': row[15].strip(),
            'on_transfer': row[16].strip(),
            'avail': row[17].strip(),
            'store_model': row[18].strip(),
            'current_cost': row[19].strip(),
        }
        cur.execute(
            """INSERT INTO 
            "Inventory"("date","store_id","store_name","model_num","upc","on_hand","on_order","on_transfer","avail","store_model","current_cost")
             select %(date)s, 
                %(store_id)s, 
                %(store_name)s, 
                %(model_num)s, 
                %(upc)s, 
                %(on_hand)s, 
                %(on_order)s,
                %(on_transfer)s,
                %(avail)s,
                %(store_model)s,
                %(current_cost)s
            ;""", arg)
```

I want to trim UPC of the leading character in the csv file without having to open excel and do a trim.

Comment: A bit more information would be helpful. Can you show a demo version of something that you would want to trim? Is it always a certain number of characters? Is it always a certain pattern? Is it always a specific thing?

Comment: @Nahkki: OP wrote `the leading character`. That should clarify it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: The OP also wrote " the UPCs in my file have leading characters" which is where my question comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing an `INSERT` command just use an expression with [`right()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
right(upc, -1)
```

... to trim `the leading character`. So:

```
...
right(%(upc)s, -1) 
...
```

But if we are talking about more than a few rows, consider `COPY` instead of `INSERT`. But then you can't execute expressions on the fly ...